# What is the meaning of this sentence from Inorganic Chemistry?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was studying Inorganic Chemistry today and I read a statement for which I wasn't able to understand the meaning.

> When Plaster of Paris is wetted with water,it forms a plastic mass which sets in from 5 to 15 minutes to a white porous hard mass.

I can understand that Plaster of Paris is treated with H<sub>2</sub>O. I cant understand next sentence . Can anyone explain this is in simple English?

Comment: I think you omitted a word, and I think it might have been water. Is it correct that you meant to say that it is wetted with **water**?

Comment: yes it is treated(wetted) with water

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plaster of Paris initially is in the powdered form. When it is mixed with water, it undergoes few chemical reactions and forms a plastic-like substance in about 5 to 15 minutes. It is porous. That means that the plastic-like has small holes in it.

Comment: what is meaning of "Porous"?

Comment: Having pores or small holes.

Answer (score 1):

You're **missing** some words. Here's the full quote from [*Modern Inorganic Chemistry*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1iQ7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA446&lpg=PA446&dq=When%20Plaster%20of%20Paris%20is%20wetted%20with,it%20forms%20a%20plastic%20mass%20which%20sets%20in%20from%205%20to%2015%20minutes%20to%20a%20white%20porous%20hard%20mass.&source=bl&ots=EFSoEILPHk&sig=kcir5XaJXNLdq2BtGWvjPbFAgLY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia7enh9LLLAhUMJiYKHcXeCFoQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=When%20Plaster%20of%20Paris%20is%20wetted%20with%2Cit%20forms%20a%20plastic%20mass%20which%20sets%20in%20from%205%20to%2015%20minutes%20to%20a%20white%20porous%20hard%20mass.&f=false) by Joseph William Mellor:

> When plaster of Paris is wetted with, **say, one-third of its weight in
>   water**, it forms a plastic mass which "sets" in from 5 to 15 minutes to
>   a white. porous, hard mass.

Clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it into stages:

Plaster of Paris - *(original form is a powder)* - when wetted *mixed with some water* it forms *becomes* a plastic *easily reshaped* mass *lump* which sets *becomes a solid* in *a period of time* from *lower limit* 5 to *upper limit* 15 minutes to *becoming* a white porous *full of little holes* hard *not easy to reshape* mass.